# Where to find documentation for what are all the parameters can be passed through kernel boot cmdline?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, bootloader

Where can I find documentation for 
`What are all the parameters that can be passed through kernel boot cmdline arguments.?`

For Eg:

1. I came across `idle=poll` as a parameter, I wanted to know its purpose.
2. and also `kmemcheck=1` for enabling kmemcheck.

So somebody give me pointers on where can i get information on all these parameters that can be passed through the cmdline to kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the `Documentation` folder of the kernel: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt

Check the file for *your* kernel to get a more specific answer for *your* kernel. You need to download the sources for that.

Also it is necessary to mention that the list of possible parameters depends on the set of loadable kernel modules used on your system. A device driver for example may introduce it's own set of parameters.

You can issue:

```
modinfo -p ${modulename}
```

to get a list of parameters supported by a certain module.